# Secure WebSockets not connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a server with node.js installed running [example websocket code](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/examples/ssl.js) from GitHub. I set the HTTPS certificate and key to the ones made by certbot (**/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem** & **/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem**) and ran it with node.js. When I connect using `const webSocket = new WebSocket('wss://mydomain.com:33411/');` on the client side, in the console it shows `WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com/' failed` on chrome and on firefox it shows `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://mydomain.com:33411/`. It shows no error on the server, and no error details on the client.

I tried using a websocket tester and it also didn't connect. I also tried totally disabling the firewall but it still, wouldn't connect.

Edit: I forgot to put this in, but if I switch `const wss = new WebSocketServer({ server });` with `const wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 2096 });` and use ws:// (not secure websockets), it works.

Comment: it's because the script is loading from a page over http instead of https

Comment: Post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Its not clear where your problem is. You also need to a certificate and a key file for tls/ssl to work.

Comment: @RudyMartin its a local development server, so it shouldnt matter.

Comment: I too have a similar setup with the exception I am using self signed certificates. But long before I could play with websockets I had to correctly setup https first, and by that I mean to be able to see it as a valid website from the browser, which also means adding CA certificate to the browser.